# Default name suggestion for files in "save as" dialog

Tags: files

I right clicked over a photo, selected **save image as..**, the save dialog appeared, and there was `207e072b-a806-4078-984d-933ae0567e6c.jpeg`in the name text box. Where has this name come from? Can we set our own naming scheme?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use "Save As" in web browser, this is typically the name of the file stored on remote server. When you use that option and file dialog appears, the name can be changed to whatever you like manually.

Certain applications allow such as screenshot utilities may allow for using certain default schema like timestamp, but overall file dialog (or at least Gtk based ones I have seen so far) allow for manual editing only.